# Comparing two-dimensional array for qsort()

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, compare, qsort

I would like to sort a 2D int array with `qsort(...)` but my comparing function seems to be wrong. The parameters of qsort are the following one:

```
qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*))
```

And my function for comparing 2D array:

```
int compareArray2D ( const void *pa, const void *pb ) {
   const int a = (const int **)pa;
   const int b = (const int **)pb;
   if (a[0] == b[0]) {
      return a[1] - b[1];
   } else {
       return a[0] - b[0];
   }
}
```

However sorting with the following function for a 1D array worked:

```
int compareArray (const void * a, const void * b) {
    return ( *(int*)b - *(int*)a );
}
```

Actually the first function goes wrong and I don't know how to fix it. Thank you for your hints.

Comment: It would help to show your calling code.

Comment: Shouldn't `const int a = (const int **)pa;` be `const int a = (const int *)*pa;`?

Comment: qsort compare functions get called with pointers to the things being compared, so you almost always need one extra level of indirection. I suspect you might need something like `const int *a = *(const int **)pa`.  But this really depends on what kind of "2D array" you're sorting: is it a static 2D array (array of array of int), or dynamic (pointer to pointer to int), or something else?

Comment: Please show us what you pass to `qsort()`, how it is defined and initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a and b to be pointers in order to use the array subscript.  Try something like this;

```
int compareArray2D ( const void *pa, const void *pb ) {
   const int* a = pa;
   const int* b = pb;
   if(a[0] == b[0]) {
      return a[1] - b[1];
   } else {
       return a[0] - b[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: Good point.  I guess I left it in since he was incorrectly casting it in his example.  I'll edit the answer

Comment: Is also dangerous to use `return a[1] - b[1];` instead of using a comparison, because the subtraction can cause overflow.

Comment: Works for me, thanks :) Please explain me why have you removed that `(const int **)` cast?